# XElement Parse error when trying to parse string

Tags: xml-parsing, asp.net-core-2.0, xelement

I am getting xml parse error while trying to parse a string (with CDATA within CDATA)

```
var cont = "<op><![CDATA[someData<p><![CDATA[someotherData]]></p></op>";
XElement.Parse(cont);
```

Error:

```
The 'op' start tag on line 1 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'p'. Line 1, position 52.
```

Can we have CDATA within CDATA ? If we can, then why am I getting the error.

Below code works fine (It does not contain CDATA within CDATA).

```
var cont = "<op><![CDATA[someData]]</op>";
XElement.Parse(cont);
```

Comment: Right... that's not valid xml. What's that closing `</p>` tag supposed to correspond to?

Comment: @JeffMercado Then what would be the closest valid xml in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1  <op>
2      <![CDATA[
3          someData
4          <p>
5              <![CDATA[someotherData]]>
6          </p>
7  </op>
```

When the XML Parser encounters the `]]>` in line 5 , it will terminate the first `<![CDATA[` it met in line 2 . As a result , **you can never have nested `CDATA` within an `CDATA`**.

`CDATA` is not designed to hold `xml`elements , but to hold character data that might contains characteres such as `<`, `>` and so on , which allows us to avoid escaping them as `&lt;` , `&gt;` respectively , and to write them and display them in a clean way .

So **the content between `<![CDATA[` and `]]`** will **be treated as plain text , with no further processing , even if it looks like that there's a hierarchy** . In other words , **they are plain strings** .  Let's take your code as an example :

```
var cont = "<op><![CDATA[ <foo><bar></bar></foo> ]]></op>";
var xml=XElement.Parse(cont);
```

Here the `FirstNode` of `xml` will be a plain text `foo><bar></bar></foo>` , and the `FirstNode` of the `FirstNode` will be `null`.

Since the parser will always treat the data between `<![CDATA[` and `]]` as a plain string , there's no "standard" closest valid way to represent them . Just encode them and decode them . For example , we can  urlencode the data :

```
string xmlstr= @"<op><![CDATA[
    <helloworld/>
    someData%0A%3Cp%3E%0A%3C!%5BCDATA%5BsomeotherData%5D%5D%3E%0A%3C%2Fp%3E
]]></op>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlstr);

var subxmlString=System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(xml.Value);
// make sure there' must be a root element
var subxml= XElement.Parse($"<root>${subxmlString}</root>");
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.